# substituting positive signed variables to unsigned variables

Tags: c++, c, variables

(In C/C++)

```
//1
int i = 1;
unsigned u = i;

//2
int i = 1;
unsigned u = (unsigned)i;

//3
unsigned u = 1;

//4
unsigned u = 1u;
```

The gcc (4.8) compiler makes no difference in the assembly code produced between 1, 2 and 3, 4 each. When writing actual code, (to me) it is often more convenient to use the form 1 and 3 unless it is outside the range of the positive signed. (such as 3,333,333,333 for 32 bit int)

With this function,

```
void mpz_set_ui (mpz_t rop, unsigned long int op)
```

I use it as,

```
mpz_set_ui(num, 3); //or an int variable in place of 3
```

, for example.

My understanding of the current C(++) standard is that it is unnecessary to explicitly state as unsigned in the above cases, but I am not sure whether in some cases there may be some additional tasks to convert from signed to unsigned, or is it always the exactly same executable when the substituted signed variable is within the range of the target unsigned variable.

Comment: It is unnecessary except when it matters for template instantiation or overload resolution.

Comment: If it's too large, then any decent compiler lets you know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no actual difference in the conversion result, the implicit and explicit conversion do the same thing. The advantage of the explicit cast, preferable `static_cast` in C++, is clarity: If you write the explicit cast, no one needs to wonder if you changed signedness on accident. I would consider 3) and 4) equally good.